# Regarding Sliders in Win UI

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, winui-3, winui

I had a little query with regards to Win UI and I was hoping someone could help me out with this. I'm new to the framework and I was playing around with sliders. Below is a picture of a slider taken from the Microsoft Documentation. I was wondering if it was possible to hide the value that pops up at the top, 85 in this case, when I drag the slider around, and if so, what property I am supposed to manipulate to do so.

Many thanks for your time, in advance!

[Image of Slider from Microsoft Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Ulk.png)

I tried looking at the documentation and reading through most of the properties they have highlighted, but there did not seem to be anything that matched the description of what I was looking for. I also tried changing certain properties that might have been related to it, but it is possible I may have overlooked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a `Popup` that you can't access directly. You need to grab it using the [VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopupsForXamlRoot()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getopenpopupsforxamlroot?view=winrt-22621) method.

Let's say your `Slider` control is named *SliderControl*.

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.SliderControl.LayoutUpdated += SliderControl_LayoutUpdated;
    }

    private void SliderControl_LayoutUpdated(object? sender, object e)
    {
        if (VisualTreeHelper
            .GetOpenPopupsForXamlRoot(this.SliderControl.XamlRoot)
            .FirstOrDefault() is Popup popup)
        {
            popup.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just tried this out, and it helped out! Very helpful!